# Avoiding breaks in vertical bars in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm having problems defining the width of a vertical line. I want those 2 lines in the pic to join:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\ {Feb, 2014 - } & Master Thesis Student \\
\ {Present} & \emph{INEB, Porto}\\ 
& \footnotesize{"Exploring degradable Gatg Dendrimers as Nucleic Acid Vectors Targeted to the Nervous System"}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\vspace{0.5em}

%------------------------------------------------

\ {Feb, 2013 - } & Intern \\
\ {Jul, 2013} & \emph{Stockholm University, Sweden}\\ 
& \footnotesize{Developed bachelor thesis at the Center for Biomembrane Research during an Erasmus Programme. "Production of secretory proteins in the periplasm of \textit{E. Coli}"}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
...
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 4):

`\vspace` inside a table cell is added *after* the current row. Use the optional argument of `\\` for additional space between rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{9cm}}
Feb, 2014 -- & Master Thesis Student \\
Present & \emph{INEB, Porto}\\
& \footnotesize
  ``Exploring degradable Gatg Dendrimers as Nucleic Acid Vectors Targeted
  to the Nervous System''\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\[.5em]
Feb, 2013 -- & Intern \\
Jul, 2013 & \emph{Stockholm University, Sweden}\\
& \footnotesize
  Developed bachelor thesis at the Center for Biomembrane Research during
  an Erasmus Programme. ``Production of secretory proteins in the periplasm
  of \textit{E. Coli}''\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The current version uses a dummy `\multicolumn` to get space without the vertical line. This can be replaced by a "pure" space via `\noalign`:

```
... & \emph{INEB, Porto}\\
\noalign{\vspace{1.7em}}
Feb, 2013 -- & ...
```

This space gets removed at page breaks if a `longtable` is used. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Add frame to show the page layout and decrease height to get a page break
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\textheight}{.1\textheight}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{r|p{9cm}}
Feb, 2014 -- & Master Thesis Student \\* % star form: no page break
Present & \emph{INEB, Porto}\\*
& \footnotesize
  ``Exploring degradable Gatg Dendrimers as Nucleic Acid Vectors Targeted
  to the Nervous System''\\
\noalign{\vspace{1.7em}}
Feb, 2013 -- & Intern \\*
Jul, 2013 & \emph{Stockholm University, Sweden}\\*
& \footnotesize
  Developed bachelor thesis at the Center for Biomembrane Research during
  an Erasmus Programme. ``Production of secretory proteins in the periplasm
  of \textit{E. Coli}''
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**Further remarks:**

- `\footnotesize` is a fonts size command that does not take an argument. If you want to limit its scope, a local group can be used:

  ```
  {\footnotesize Smaller font} Normal font
  ```

  A table cell in LaTeX implicitly puts the contents in a group, thus explicit group braces are not needed.
- I have fixed the quotation marks: In English ``` `` ``` and `''` can be used. TeX converts them to the right quotation marks.
- Usually the en dash `--` is used for ranges in opposite to the smaller hyphen `-`.
- I have removed the unclear `\ {...}`.

Comment: Very much appreciated!